Groups for local users in pgadmin4 (web server mode)
I have a containerized setup of pgAdmin4 V8.5 in server mode running.
Does anyone know if I can create groups for local users in pgadmin4 in web server mode and set privileges for them?
Basic idea

To have one user with administrative privileges and who would have a list of databases (by server.json and .pgpass files) and give access by sharing database to individual groups or users.

For example pgadmin4 has 3 users:
- user admin@example.com has a list of 3 Postgresql databases (DB1, DB2 and DB3) and is in the admins group
- user user1@example.com is in the readers group
- user user2@example.com, is in the writers group
User admin@example.com shares DB1 only to the readers group and DB2 only to the writers group.
Users user1@example.com and user2@example.com avoid having to manually configure database connections when authorizing in pgadmin4 and get the list of databases from user admin@example.com.
Maybe does anyone know any forks pgadmin4 (server mode) or any another applications which supports this idea I'd appreciate the information!
Thanks in advance!
